# What would be a good threshold value to determine the differences between means?

Tags: probability, t-test, threshold

We have a dataset with 5 outcomes. The outcomes are categorical. We ran classification model and obtained the classification and prediction probabilities for each outcomes separately. For business purposes, We’re interested in finding mean differences in the probabilities between two groups - Group A vs Group B. For this, we ran regular 2 sample t-test (Mann Whitney test) and found some of them significant. However, the confusing part for us is that difference in mean probabilities for 2 outcomes is very low (0.042) and still significant, and it’s bit difficult to explain customers if they should consider monitoring the outcome.

So, is there a way to create or fine a threshold value that states that if the differences of mean probabilities are above or below this threshold value, then it’s something they should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good on you for considering effect sizes vs. significancy. The thing is, a p-value tells you, this difference is very surprising if the null-hypothesis (there is no difference) is true. However, it says nothing substantial about if it's actually a big difference. This is a major confusion when you talk about a significant result, because statistically significant can be an arbitrarily small effect size, not significant at all in human speak so to say. This happens if you have a lot of data, and your p-value will become very small because you are able to detect even the smallest of differences, and all results will be significant. Unless of course the group don't differ at all, but in reality, that will almost certainly not be the case. Your question is really, how can I estimate effect size, and at what size is it actually of importance? The latter is a completely arbitrary decision depending on the business context. A 50% increased chance of death is probably important to you, but whether you consider a 1% increased conversion rate a big thing or not, that's up to you probably. As to estimating effect size, that is the fitted coefficient you get from your model.

Comment: thank you for your feedback and clarifying answer. What I read is that it should be enough to show `cohen's d`, is that correct? Then based on the effect size, we can make our own business case and state whether the difference is truly meaningful or not.

Comment: It depends on the setup of your model what exactly the effect size is. And this cohen's d takes into account again some measure of noise, I don't think that's correct. You can have a very clear but small effect, and then the effect can be reliable, or it can be noisy (on average, there is a clear effect, but the effect range is big). I'm not sure what cohen's d measures.

Comment: Got it. That's very helpful. And I found papers discussing just that https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.2466/11.IT.3.1 and  http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/docs30/CL.pdf

Comment: Allright! Good luck, I must say I'm not entirely confident on my knowledge in that area. I actually use Bayesian frameworks for a model like this, which works well for me. Perhaps interesting for you as well, https://xcelab.net/rm/statistical-rethinking/ is a great resource to start with that.